# React - Array sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render different state depending on where the user is on the page.
This is some pseudo code of what im trying to achieve

I've got that for all pages

```js
const [page1, setPage1] = useState(false)

const [seq] = useState([...[props.exampleDom1 ? 1 : 0, props.exampleDom2 ? 2 : 0], 3].filter(Number))

const seq = () => {
  if (props.exampleDom1) {
    [setPage1 THEN setPage3]
  } else if (props.exampleDom2) {
    [setPage2 THEN setPage3]
  }
}
```

then I could just use SEQ to fetch views to show

Essentially, if `props.ExampleDom1` is true, then `setPage1` to show (which is in state) and then setPage3,
if `props.ExampleDom2` is true then do a difference sequence > Page 2 then Page 3